# Python "OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0)" when using script to load and detect faces from a given directory path

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

I'm trying to load a set of images from a given directory, detect and count how many faces are detected there.
My code looks like this:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os

def read_images():
    path1 = '/home/sousajf1/Documents/opencv/facedetect/data'   
    path2 = '/home/sousajf1/Documents/opencv/facedetect/dataprocessed'    
    countFace=0
    listing = os.listdir(path1)    
for file in listing:
    img = cv2.imread('path1 + file',0)
    faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_profileface.xml')
    eyeCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')
    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(img, 1.3, 5)
    cv2.imshow('img',img)
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (255,0,0), 2)
        roiGray=gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roiColor=img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    
    if len(faces)!=0:
        countFace+=1

    #cv2.imwrite(path2 + file, "JPEG")

print countFace
cv2.waitKey(0)

read_images()
```

But when I run this I get always 0 faces detected. I thought maybe there were no images being loaded at all, so I added the `cv2.imshow` line before the first for and I got the following error:

`OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0`

which is probably because there no image at all to show.

The code seems right to me, and I have no idea what to do now.
Would appreciate some help and a fresh mind. Thanks guys.

**UPDATE**

I've now tried using the `glob` function, but it still did not work:

```py
import cv2
import glob
countFace = 0
countEyes = 0
for img in glob.glob("/home/sousajf1/Documents/opencv/*.pgm"):

cvImg = cv2.imread(img,0)
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_profileface.xml')
eyeCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')
#gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(cvImg, 1.3, 5)
#cv2.imshow('img',cvImg)
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(cvImg, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (255,0,0), 2)
    roiGray=gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    roiColor=cvImg[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    eyes=eyeCascade.detectMultiScale(roiGray)
    for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
        cv2.rectangle(roiColor, (ex,ey), (ex+ew, ey+eh), (0,255,0), 1)
        if len(eyes)>0:
            countEyes = countEyes +1
if len(faces)>0:
    countFace = countFace +1

    
print countFace
print countEyes
```

Comment: The reason you get the assertion is that you don't validate the result of `cv2.imread` before you use it. When this function fails to load the image, you end up with an empty image. It's not valid for the first parameter of `detectMultiScale` to be a valid image. | As to why it doesn't read it, it might be useful to first test whether such file exists. Maybe the path is malformed? You can easily test that, and produce a meaningful error message.

Comment: I think that indent is the problem here. for loop is outside of `read_images` function and it is going first,so listing is empty,and your code cannot load any images. Indent `for` loop inside `read_images()`, and of course, go with @Adam for proper reading image.

Comment: I've noticed it @Aleksandar, still didn't work, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read a filename as a string

```
img = cv2.imread('path1 + file',0)
```

is not right it will be searching for a file called path1 + file.

Try this:

```
img = cv2.imread('{0}{1}'.format(path1, file),0)
```

Comment: Thanks Adam. I still get 0 faces, and putting the imshow the same "Assertion Failed"

Comment: You are missing a `/` between the two parts. It is better to use `os.path.join` or `pathlib.Path` to avoid this manual work... `os.path.join(path1, file)` or `pathlib(Path(path1, file)`

Answer (score 0):

> Solution:

`imshow` fails when you pass an empty image. In your case, this is most likely due to the fact that you ignore empty frames from `cap.read()` and call `imshow` even if `cap.read` returned an empty image.

To fix this, replace your `while True loop` with a `while cap.isOpened()` or check whether `cap.isOpened()` has been successful before reading frames.